# "Uncaught ReferenceError: snap is not defined"

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
//creating references 
const dbRefObject = firebase.database().ref().child("object");

//syn object changes

dbRefObject.on('value', snap => console.log(snap.val()));

preObject.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(snap.val(), null, 3);
```

On the last line, it says that `snap` is not defined. How do I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see how and what to ask. HINT: Post a [mcve] instead of some arbitrary code and a demand for fixes. How would snap suddenly acquire a value unless it is a defined html field? If so where is the field?

Answer (score 1):

If you switch back to classic JavaScript notation your code is equivalent to his:

```
function callback(snap) { 
    console.log(snap.val()) 
}

//creating references 
const dbRefObject = firebase.database().ref().child("object");

//syn object changes

dbRefObject.on('value', callback);

preObject.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(snap.val(), null, 3);
```

With that it's probably easier to see why you can't access `snap` on the last line: the `snap` variable is only define/available in the callback function.

Even if you'd declare `snap` globally the code would work, since the callback is triggered asynchronously. So by the lime you call `snap.val()` now, the callback (and this `snap`) won't be available yet.

The solution is to move the code that needs access to the snapshot *into* the callback:

```
//creating references 
const dbRefObject = firebase.database().ref().child("object");

//syn object changes

dbRefObject.on('value', snap => {
    preObject.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(snap.val(), null, 3);
});
```